# Linking div click event to angular filter checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-digest

I am working with an angular checkbox filter based on the one in this jsfiddle (from another question). http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/502/

I don't want to use the default checkboxes so I have 'linked' two div's to the checkboxes using jquery like this:

```
var toggleVar = 0;
$("#check-1").bind('click', function() {
    if(toggleVar % 2 == 0) {
        $(".check-item:first-child input").prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $(".check-item:first-child input").prop('checked', false);
    }
    toggleVar++;
});
});
```

My jquery works correctly with the html and checks the box, but the angular model doesn't detect the change and fails to 'refresh' itself (digest?) to update the filtered output (see jsfiddle for context).

What do I need to add to ensure that the angular model will detect the click, or detect the jquery-made change in the checkboxes' status? Do I write changes into the jquery file or in the angular controller?

I understand it's messy to work with jquery and angular, so if there is an angular-only option please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific example, if I get the goal correctly all code that has to trigger the checkbox can be put inside a `label`. That way the checkbox is checked automatically

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="usePants[pants]"/><b>{{pants}}</b></label>
```

A more generic approach in case the 'triggering' div is more disconnected, is to update the data field itself inside `ng-click` (e.g.`usePants[pants] = !usePants[pants]` ). Only caveat is that you can't bind to the containing div or bold element, unless you stopPropagation. Otherwise clicking the checkbox itself would double fire. An alternative here is to use an extra span or to move the `b` element so it does not contain the input.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="usePants[pants]"/><b ng-click="usePants[pants]= !usePants[pants]">{{pants}}</b>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzgWr/506/)

Of course I might be misinterpreting the question altogether. This is assuming that clicking the text next to the checkbox updates both checkbox and triggers the angularisjs filtering.